# Animating LayoutParams vs. Translation and Scale in Android

Tags: java, android, animation, kotlin, mobile-development

It seems like the code for animating a view's scale and translation is always much more clean and concise (e.g. using `.animate()`) than code that animates the view's LayoutParams (i.e. width, height, etc.) which requires the use of animators (`ValueAnimator`, `ObjectAnimator`, etc.)

That made me wonder whether animating a certain view's LayoutParams is considered a bad practice, or if it's "heavier" than animating the view's translation and scale properties?

Also, couldn't find any answers for this on SO so it would be great if anyone could shed some light on the subject.

Comment: the more clean way is [Scenes and Transitions](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/index.html)

Comment: @pskink what if support for lower APIs (16+) is required?

Comment: did you read the whole page i posted?

Comment: @pskink Missed the note at the bottom, sorry... I'll see if it fits my needs and post back for any updates, thanks!

Comment: you are welcome...

Comment: @pskink it worked just great, if you could post your comment as an answer I will accept it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @pskink, a cleaner way to perform transitions and animations inside an activity/fragment/layout is using [scenes and transitions](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/index.html) which was exactly what I did, and with some adaption worked just perfect!

Comment: its nice it worked, support lib is a bit limited but still it gives good results

Answer (score 0):

If you have more complex layout and try to animate through layoutParams you will quickly see stutter because on every frame it triggers `requestLayout()` and parent ViewGroup must execute `onMeasure()` and `onLayout()` for entire view hierarchy.

Comment: thats why you should use [scenes and transitions](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/index.html)